# Use Crawler Component to parse XML

Tags: xml, symfony

I Want to parse XML and I wanto to collect some information

I tried with

```
 $crawler = new Crawler();
 $crawler->addXmlContent($readXml->getXml());
```

But I have this result

```
object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler)[747]
  protected 'uri' => null
  private 'defaultNamespacePrefix' => string 'default' (length=7)
  private 'namespaces' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'baseHref' => null
```

How can I read the xml files?

I tried also

```
$crawler->addXmlContent(file_get_contents($readXml->getXml()));
```

and

```
    $document = new \DOMDocument();
    $document->loadXml(file_get_contents($readXml->getXml()));
```

But in this way I don't know How can I read $document with $crawler

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, localy everything works, once in the server the Crawler fails to parse the xml string.
I get empty body, no namespaces and also no detected encoding.
did you solve the issue ? if so kindly can you please share the solution or the workarround ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the `Crawler`'s content directly via the constructor

```
$crawler = new Crawler($readXml->getXml());
```

That way it isn't added to the current nodes, since there are no nodes yet.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#usage